# Combine two date columns together to one in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to combine a start and end column into one single date column.

```
start             end              id

10/01/2020        11/01/2020       a
```

Desired output

Date                               id

```
10/01/2020 to 11/01/2020           a
```

**OR**

```
 Date                            id

10/01/2020  11/01/2020            a
```

This is what I am doing

```
df1 = df['Date'] = df['start'] + "To " + df['end']


df11.info()
1   start  188 non-null    datetime64[ns]
2   end    188 non-null    datetime64[ns]
```

I am still researching this, I think I may need to do a conversion to Datetime, however, I see that both of the columns I wish to combine already has a datetime type. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Date']= df.apply(lambda x: x['start'] + ' '+'to'+ ' '+x['end'],1)
```

Or

```
df['Date']=df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x:x['start'].str.cat(x['end'], sep=' to '))



 start         end id                      Date
0  10/01/2020  11/01/2020  a  10/01/2020 to 11/01/2020
```

Comment: ok thank you I will try, and to add the new column name, would I just do: df['NewColumn']=df.apply(lambda x: x['start'] + ' '+'to'+ ' '+x['end'],1)

Comment: Yes, jus `df['Date']=df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x:x['start'].str.cat(x['end'], sep=' to '))`

Comment: I am getting the error:  unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str', yet both column names start and end are datetime64.

Comment: Ok, just dtypes issues. You need to convert your dates to str

Comment: Please try `df.apply(lambda x: x['start'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' '+'to'+ ' '+x['end'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),1)`

Comment: Hello. I did this: df['Sstart']=df['start'].astype(str)
df['end']=df11['end'].astype(str), but now I get this error: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index - which I am researching now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224224/discussion-between-wwnde-and-lynnette).